# vue-stripe-elements - Configuration of one file

Tags: javascript, json

I'm tyrnig to use `vue-stripe-elements` https://github.com/fromatob/vue-stripe-elements.

It is mentionned `import { stripeKey, stripeOptions } from './stripeConfig.json'`

But I don't know what the file `stripeConfig.json` should look like. I'm sure it should contains my `stripe` keys but I don't know which format it should be.

Answer (score 4):

Per this [this Github issue](https://github.com/fromAtoB/vue-stripe-elements/issues/1), I originally addressed this by renaming `./stripeConfig.json` to `./stripeConfig.js` and entering the following:

```
export const stripeKey = 'pk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
export const stripeOptions = {}
```

Just fill in the X part with your public key from Stripe.

Regarding `stripeOptions` being empty, this worked as a basic config for me, but I think you can fill in other options by referring to [Stripe Elements Documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/elements).

Later, I decided to skip loading the `.js` file altogether and simply return those variables from my `data` function.

Hope that helps!